# Python 3: How to automatically create index with json variable and send to Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I wanted to create an index from my json variable which got from using curl and its contains these data

```
{
"test.mydomain.xyz:1019":{
"infoAddr":"x.x.x.x:1022",
"infoSecureAddr":"x.x.x.x:0",
"xferaddr":"x.x.x.x:1019",
"lastContact":6,
"usedSpace":384635032546,
"adminState":"In Service",
"nonDfsUsedSpace":283930161,
"capacity":30697676811776,
"numBlocks":24322,
"version":"2.7.3.2.6.5.23-1",
"used":384635032546,
"remaining":30311575148182,
"blockScheduled":6,
"blockPoolUsed":384635032546,
"blockPoolUsedPercent":1.2529777,
"volfails":0,
"lastBlockReport":207,
"clusterName":"test.mydomain.xyz:1019"
},
```

Then I known I have to create an index also mapping but I dunno what should I starting with. Searching from google seems doesn't help much.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by creating an index? We can see the data you have as input. But what is your expected output?

Comment: Simple example available here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py#example-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by create a mapping first, this would be the best pratice according to your example. You have to tell to es witch field need to be indexed (= searchable) and how. For exemple, in your exemple clusterName and version should be KeyWord. This would optimise the cluster (in ressource and performance). Second solution, quick and dirty, juste index some document and elastic will create mapping for you. Note once the mapping of an index created, it cant be updated (except by adding new fields). If you change mapping you have to reacreate index and reindex data.